# Angular Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a board with four columns, each column is fill with n number of items, when i click in one of the items, the details section that is in a sidenav should be loaded, For some reason that i still can get why...i´m getting this error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'HyPE4PM/2/details/5413869/DETAILS'` every time i try to open the details section in my project. the way it is right now my `app.module` is lazy loading `backlog.module` and my backlog module is lazy loading `board.module` as children and the `board.module` is lazy loading the `details.module` as children.

**app-routing.module**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'HyPE4PM',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/lazy/backlog.module').then((mod) => mod.BacklogModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'Error',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/lazy/error-site.module').then((mod) => mod.ErrorSiteModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
```

**backlog-routing.module**

```
/**
 * define the routes for the BacklogComponent module
 */
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: BacklogComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../lazy/boards-modules/taskboard.module').then((mod) => mod.TaskboardModule)
      },
    ]
  }
];

/**
 * define the routing for the BacklogComponent module
 */
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**board-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TaksboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'details/:id', redirectTo: 'details/:id/DETAILS', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'details/:id/:detailsSection',
        loadChildren: () => import('../lazy/backlog-item-details.module').then((mod) => mod.BacklogItemDetailsModule),
        outlet: 'rightSidenav',
        data: { preload: true, delay: 2500 }
      }
    ]
  }
];

/**
 * define the routing for the BacklogComponent module
 */
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Then i´m using the `router.navigate` to go the details of the selected item:

```
  public selectItem(event: MouseEvent, position: DetailSections) {
    this.log.trace(`selectItem() in backlog item comp. id: ${this.backlogItem.id}`);
    this.eventService.hideBoardCreator.emit();
    // as the click to these events are bound on the DOM on childs of the click to the details -> we need to stop the event here
    // if TS on other card is shown, it needs to be hidden
    event.stopPropagation();

    // save selection into store
    this.store.dispatch(new BacklogItemSelected(this.backlogItem));

    // show the details section
    this.router.navigate([`/HyPE4PM/${this.configService.boardtype}/details`, this.backlogItem.id, DetailSections[position]]);
  }
```

here i share a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppxunc)  of the error, as you can see in the example if you try to go to the route `hype/2/details` you will get error.

Comment: can you share your stackblitz of problem here?

Comment: where you define`details/:id/DETAILS` route?

Comment: the  `details/:id/DETAILS` route is not defined as you can see in the `board-routing.module`, the defined router  is `details/:id/:detailsSection` and in case that there is not `:detailsSection` param in the router i´m redirecting to `details/:id/DETAILS`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda i will try to reproduce the error in a stackblitz.

Comment: I just updated the question with a stackblitz of the error

Answer (score 0):

add new path:'details in board-routing.module like this..

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BoardComponent } from './board.component';

/**
    * Define all available routes
*/
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: BoardComponent,
    children: [
   {
      path: 'details',
      loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then((mod) => mod.DetailsModule),
    outlet: 'details'
  }
]
},{
    path: 'details',
loadChildren: () => import('./details/details.module').then((mod) => mod.DetailsModule)
 }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class BoardRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: That´s not gonna work, you can not have the same route two times loading the same module, and one as root the again as children that´s is not gonna work.

Comment: Have you tested it. before voting down ?

Comment: Yes i tested, first the idea is to load the module as children, if you check you solution when load the module details the module board is gone. that is the idea of loading the module as children of the board module

Comment: 1. put one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in board.component.html and then in board-routing.module.ts remove ` outlet: 'details' in children path of 'details'. rest will work as what you desired to work..

Comment: @GaurantDhorda the reason why i put the two `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is because there where i need to display both component is not matter of where i place the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ( basically that is structure of the applicacion and i can no be changed ), that is the idea of name in the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk9evs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html check this stackblitz. you must have to do some change in your app routing behavior.